# android studio duplicate entry error

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been searching for three days in the following error and I don't know what is the problem

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:_4SaleApp:assembleDebug]
:_4SaleApp:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:checkDebugManifest
:ffmpeg4android_lib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:preBuild
:ffmpeg4android_lib:preReleaseBuild
:_4SaleApp:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:preReleaseBuild
:_4SaleApp:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:generateDebugBuildConfig
:gestureimageview:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:compileLint
:ffmpeg4android_lib:compileLint
:gestureimageview:copyReleaseLint
:ffmpeg4android_lib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
:gestureimageview:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
:ffmpeg4android_lib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:checkReleaseManifest
:_4SaleApp:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:gestureimageview:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:compileReleaseRenderscript
:_4SaleApp:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:compileDebugNdk
:gestureimageview:checkReleaseManifest
:_4SaleApp:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:packageReleaseResources
:gestureimageview:prepareReleaseDependencies
:_4SaleApp:validateDebugSigning
:gestureimageview:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:packageReleaseResources
:ffmpeg4android_lib:compileReleaseAidl
:gestureimageview:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:gestureimageview:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:ffmpeg4android_lib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:mergeReleaseAssets
:gestureimageview:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:mergeReleaseAssets
:ffmpeg4android_lib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:processReleaseManifest
:gestureimageview:processReleaseManifest
:ffmpeg4android_lib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:processReleaseResources
:gestureimageview:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:ffmpeg4android_lib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:gestureimageview:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:gestureimageview:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:ffmpeg4android_lib:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepare4SaleApp_StudioFfmpeg4android_libUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepare4SaleApp_StudioGestureimageviewUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2300Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132200Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComAppboyAndroidSdkUi1112Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComCommonswareCwacCamera0610Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGithubBmelnychukAtv128Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGithubJaydeepwPolyPickerV1022Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable830Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComWdullaerMaterialdatetimepicker202Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareComZopimAndroidSdk110Library UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:prepareDebugDependencies
:_4SaleApp:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:_4SaleApp:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':_4SaleApp:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: bo/app/a.class
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1 mins 9.134 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

can anyone help please ??

**EDIT**

this is my gradle file, it may help

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6'
        classpath 'com.mutualmobile.gradle.plugins:dexinfo:0.1.2'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.forsale.forsale"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 15
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {

        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libblasV8.so'
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    /*lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }*/
}

repositories {

    jcenter()

    maven {
        url 'https://zendesk.artifactoryonline.com/zendesk/repo/'
    }

    maven {
        url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
    }

    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }

    maven {
        url "http://appboy.github.io/appboy-android-sdk/sdk"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':gestureimageview')
    compile project(':ffmpeg4android_lib')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-hipmob-2.9.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/HockeySDK-3.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/libphonenumber-5.2v1.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/NineOldAndroid-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.commons.io.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/zbar.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-core-2.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-chat-2.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-content-2.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-messages-2.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/renderscript-v8.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.zopim.android:sdk:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.jaydeepw:poly-picker:v1.0.22'
    compile 'com.github.bmelnychuk:atv:1.2.+'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.appboy:android-sdk-ui:1.11.2'
    compile 'com.danikula:videocache:2.3.4'
}
```

Comment: I'd think there is an error with your Proguard configuration.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall android studio? Not the sdk just the IDE

Comment: @Jey10 I just did that and the error is still exist, I had android studio version 1.5.1 and now I upgrade to android studio 2.1 and the problem still found

Comment: Have you tried to do this command in the root project folder : ./gradlew clean

Comment: @Jey10 yes I run this command multi times and I get build successful, but when I run the app on real device or on simulator I get the error again

Comment: Once, I had a similar issue due to multidex. I solved it by creating another app, new app, then copy all java and xml into the new app. It's maybe due to your app that is corrupted, try with a new one

Comment: He needs multidexing because he added the whole Play Services instead of just the module.